# Insert values passed via URL into a generated form

Tags: php, forms

I'm using gravity forms on a page. When the form is validated the user arrives on a page with a payment form (Mollie).

Mollie has mandatory fields (first name, name...). Since I want to avoid users to retype those infos I'm passing these values via the URL and recuperate them in my template.

How can I now insert those values into the right fields ? I don't have access to the fields' code since it's generated by Mollie API.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Answer the question

can use `$_REQUEST` to show value input

Comment: The fields are empty when I arrive on the page. I'd like to populate those with the passed ones.

Comment: if  `$_GET`  and `$_REQUEST` are not feasible you can save data to `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it's a GET request to the his page.

For example you create a form which will send to the next page something like that in the URL:

example.com?name=Fabio&age=30

So in your `nextpage.php` you can retrieve the data from url in that way:

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['name'];
$age = $_GET['age'];
```

Just a disclaimer: this isn't the most security and correct way to do it and isn't the "right" let's say. If you are sending some sensitive information **please avoid or just simply don't use it.**

You can do the same by using the **POST** method also with just the simply difference of:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
```

But again, beware of sensitive information, you can make a clean of your inputs using some PHP functions as per the discussion here in the stackoverflow bellow:

[How can I sanitize user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/how-can-i-sanitize-user-input-with-php)

If you can avoid to do this hands on work preferrer to use a framework like:

https://laravel.com
https://symfony.com

And some others you can research.

[EDIT]

As per @hùng nguyễn answered bellow, you can also use $_REQUEST global do retrieve this values.

And you can see all the values is on request trough:

```
<?php

print_r($_REQUEST);
```

[EDIT 2]

**Thanks Fabio but how can I insert the values into the form fields ?**

To insert the values into the form fields you can see the example as reference, using $_GET:

```
<form>
  <input value="<?=$_GET['name'];?>" name='name' id='name' type='text' />
  <input value="<?=$_GET['age'];?>" name='age' id='age' type='text' />
</form>
```

Example with $_POST:

```
<form>
  <input value="<?=$_POST['name'];?>" name='name' id='name' type='text' />
  <input value="<?=$_POST['age'];?>" name='age' id='age' type='text' />
</form>
```

I hope that helped you out.

Comment: Thanks Fabio but how can I insert the values into the form fields ?

Comment: @Horratio I updated my answer adding a example, please upvote and marke as answer if helped you out to help anothers users too.

Comment: Thanks Fabio ! Almost there. Last question, I get a link to a file but the system is adding language in the url making it unusable. How can I remove ?lang=fr before displaying my URL ? Thanks